# Error in SQL syntax DATATIME option

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I started to a new php script, and I used for the first time the DATATIME option in mysql. I think it makes the problem.

My sql table is :

```
id int(6) auto_increment,
name varchar(40) not null,
pseudo varchar(40) not null,
email varchar(40) not null,
password varchar(40) not null,
plan varchar(40) not null,
date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
points int(6) not null,
primary key(id,name,pseudo,email,password,date,points,plan)
```

When I try to execute this query:

```
insert into users(NULL,"name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",NULL,
"100");
```

This error displays :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'NULL,
>   "name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",NULL,"100")' at line 1

Comment: why you have such a big composite key primary `key(id,name,pseudo,email,password,date,points,plan)`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, and

```
insert into users(name,pseudo,email,password,paln,date,poits)
values("name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",'', NULL, "100");
```

plan varchar(40) not null,

What they missed is plan is not null, and either enter null for date or I would prefer to just omit it completely.

```
insert into users(name,pseudo,email,password,paln,poits)
values("name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",'', "100");
```

If you count the fields and the inputs in some of the above responses they are not equal.  The field list is optional in the insert but i would use them, for readability and to make sure you have the order and number of inputs correct.

Last thing change to the primary key, to just the auto increment field, if you need other compound indexes, you should add them separate and make unique as your requirements would require. Primary keys should be a surrogate key, as defined this way

- the value is unique system-wide, hence never reused
- the value is system generated
- the value is not manipulable by the user or application
- the value contains no semantic meaning
- the value is not visible to the user or application
- the value is not composed of several values from different domains.

The other keys should relate to the data, and like i said if you need a compound unique key, or just a unique filed like email make it separate from the primary one.

Comment: Thank you so much .. i had long time without mysql .. thanks for reminding :))) (y)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    insert into users(name,pseudo,email,password,paln,date,poits)
 values("name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",NULL, "100");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add your table field name which you want to insert values with `values` keyword. also auto increment id can not be `NULL` if you dont want to send `id, date`
values leave that it both will collect values auto with increment and current timestamp

```
 insert into users(name,pseudo,email,password,plan,points) values ('name','pseudo','email@email.com','Pass1919','','100');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the keyword values:

```
insert into users values(NULL,"name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",NULL,
"100");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass first parameter as `NULL`, as you already specified it as primary key and auto increment also.
use this

```
insert into users values("name","pseudo","email@email.com","Pass1919",NULL, "100");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO users(
  `name`,
  `pseudo`,
  `email`,
  `password`,
  `plan`,
  `points`
)
VALUES (
  NULL, 
 'name', 
 'pseudo', 
 'email@email.com', 
 'Pass1919', 
 NULL, 
 '100');
```

Comment: @user3779014 do not forgot to accept/upvote if helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, when you are dealing with integers you do not need to enclose it in quotations when inserting so you can do

```
      insert into users(name,pseudo,email,password,plan,date,points)
 values("name","pseudo","joe.bloggs@mydomain.com","S3CuR3", "PLAN", "2014-06-26", 100);
```